# mailto: acknowledgement status

Tags: c++, windows, mailto

My windows C++ app has a HTML form in which I am generating a ***mailto*** link. Once the user clicks on it, goes to his/her email client and sends the message, is there a way for me to know in the app if the ***mailto*** succeeded?

My gut feeling on the answer is no. In any case checking with the smart folks here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is *no way* for you to know if an email reached its recipient - unless you get a mail (or other communication) back from the recipient saying they got it.

Comment: Or if they click a link in your mail.

Comment: @rustyx which I'd consider equal to "getting a mail back ..". Basically, unless the recipient takes some form of action you can't know if they got your mail.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i am a newbie to html world. Can we insert something in the email meta info to know that has been sent.